# disable primary key using liquibase changeset

Tags: liquibase

How to create primary key with disable status using liquibase changeset?

I want to create partitioned index of primary key with storage parameters like init trans and max trans using liquibase changeset.

so first, I used to create primary key on column, then disable primarykey which drop unique index, than create partitioned index on primary key and than enable primarykey.

How to achieve in liquibase?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in Liquibase currently would be using the `<sql>` or `<sqlFile>` change types.